# Computing depth of each node in a "maximally packed" DAG

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, graphing, directed-acyclic-graphs

*(Note: I thought about asking this on https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/, but decided my question is not theoretical enough -- it's about an algorithm.  If there is a better Stack Exchange community for this post, I'm happy to listen!)*

I'm using the terminology "starting node" to mean a node with no links into it, and "terminal node" to mean a node with no links out of it.  So the following graph has starting nodes A and B and terminal nodes F and G:

[image: image of a Directed Acyclic Graph]

I want to draw it with the following rules:

- at least one starting node has a depth of 0.
- links always point from top to bottom
- nodes are packed vertically as closely as possible

Using those rules, depth of for each node is shown for the graph above.  Can someone suggest an algorithm to compute the depth of each node that runs in less than O(n^2) time?

#### update:

I tweaked the graph to show that the DAG may contain starting and terminal nodes at different depths.  (This was a case that I didn't consider in my original buggy answer.)  I also switched terminology from "x coordinate" to "depth" in order to emphasize that this is about "graphing" and not "graphics".

Comment: Do you mean less than O(n^2) for each node, or for the entire graph?  If you mean the entire graph, there is no such algorithm, because you have n nodes with up to n parents to check.  If you mean each node, and you are willing to compute the entire graph left-to-right, this can be implemented in O(n^2) for the whole graph, and O(n) for each node, trivially easily.

Comment: You may be interested in a splay tree - where newly accessed nodes bubble to the top of the tree. Over time the most accessed are close to the top (and therefore search the fastest) and infrequently accessed nodes are pushed down to the leaves.

Answer (score 0):

Your `x` coordinate of a node corresponds to the longest way from any node without incomming edges to this node in question. For a DAG it can be calculated in `O(N)`:

```
given DAG G:
  calculate incomming_degree[v] for every v in G
  initialize queue q={v with incomming_degree[v]==0}, x[v]=0 for every v in q
  while(q not empty):
     v=q.pop()  #retreive and delete first element
     for(w in neighbors of v):
          incomming_degree[w]--
          if(incomming_degree[w]==0): #no further way to w exists, evaluate
               q.offer(w)
               x[w]=x[v]+1
```

`x` stores the desired information.

Comment: I think this solution has the same flaw that my deleted solution had: if there are multiple starting nodes (incoming degree = 0) at different levels of the DAG, they won't get properly set since there's no "back propagation".   The best I can find is a two-pass version.

Comment: @fearless_fool sorry, didn't get what your "nodes are packed as closely as possible along the X axis with a minimum spacing of 1 unit" exactly meant.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution which is essentially a two-pass depth-first tree walk.  The first pass (traverseA) traces the DAG from the starting nodes (A and B in the O.P.'s example) until encountering terminal nodes (F and G in the example).  It them marks them with the maximum depth as traced through the graph.

The second pass (traverseB) starts at the terminal nodes and traces back towards the starting nodes, marking each node along the way with the node's current value OR the previous node's value minus one, whichever is smaller if the node hasn't been visited yet:

```
function labelDAG() {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) { node.depth = -1; });  // initialize
    // find and mark terminal nodes
    startingNodes().forEach(function(node) { traverseA(node, 0); });
    // walk backwards from the terminal nodes
    terminalNodes().forEach(function(node) { traverseB(node); });
    dumpGraph();
};

function traverseA(node, depth) {
    var targets = targetsOf(node);
    if (targets.length === 0) {
        // we're at a leaf (terminal) node -- set depth
        node.depth = Math.max(node.depth, depth);
    } else {
        // traverse each subtree with depth = depth+1
        targets.forEach(function(target) {
            traverseA(target, depth+1);
        });
    };
};

// walk backwards from a terminal node, setting each source node's depth value
// along the way.
function traverseB(node) {
    sourcesOf(node).forEach(function(source) {
        if ((source.depth === -1) || (source.depth > node.x - 1)) {
            // source has not yet been visited, or we found a longer path
            // between terminal node and source node.
            source.depth = node.depth - 1;
        }
        traverseB(source);
    });
};
```